# docker centos6にrailsを入れる

Tags: docker, rubygems

お世話になります。

dockerを使用してcentos6コンテナにrailsがインストールすることができません。
下記のコマンドをシェルで入力するとエラーメッセージも出現せず処理が進みません。
macのアクティビティモニタを確認するとVBoxHeadlessの%cpuが100%付近まで上昇します。

- ホストos mac10.14.1

#### docker環境

- centos6.1
- rbenv 1.1.1-40-g483e7f9
- ruby 1.8.7 p374

#### 試したコマンド

`gem install rails -v 2.3.11`

また古いバージョンが原因かと考えバージョン指定なしでも反応はありませんでした。
ユーザはrootで実行しています。

解決方法のご教示、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: > `コマンドをシェルで入力` したのはコンテナ内でしょうか？

Comment: 返信遅くなりすみません。macのシェルで  docker start <CONTAINER ID>、 docker attach <CONTAINER ID>　と順に入力して立ち上がったシェルで入力しました。こちらがコンテナ内のシェルという認識で間違い無いでしょうか？